# Is my Lotto Python script running correctly?

Tags: python, random

Is the script I wrote actually working correctly? I was trying to mimic a lotto picking scenario, just to see how actually impossible it is to pick the right numbers (and to show it to friends, who are playing).

The rules of the lotto game mimics the "EuroJackpot" game, where you need to pick 5 out 50 and(!) 2 out of 10. See [here](https://lotto.de/eurojackpot)

Here is my script:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

import random

given = [[8, 16, 12, 46, 47], [2, 4]]

def pickRandomNumbers():
    # source: stackoverflow.com/a/9755548/11160383
    fiveOutOf50 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 5)
    twoOutOf10 = random.sample(range(1, 10), 2)

    fiveOutOf50.sort()
    twoOutOf10.sort()

    return [fiveOutOf50, twoOutOf10]

# source: stackoverflow.com/a/61960902/11160383
def colored(r, g, b, text):
    return "\033[38;2;{};{};{}m{} \033[38;2;255;255;255m".format(r, g, b, text)


solution = pickRandomNumbers()
while given != solution:
    if(given.__contains__(solution[0]) and given.__contains__(solution[1])):
        print(colored(0, 255, 0, solution))
    else:
        print(colored(255, 0, 0, solution))
        solution = pickRandomNumbers()
```

It has a `given` which is the players choice of numbers. A while loop is picking random numbers until it matches the players choice. I let it run for a long time but apparently never matched...

Comment: Have you calculated the odds of getting a match? How many iterations do you expect until getting a match?

Comment: Apparently it has a chance of 1:96 million - so it is quite slim. But is the while loop correct? Python is not my first language of choice

Comment: BTW `x.__contains__ y` should be written as `y in x`.

Comment: Your question says "pick 10 out of 50...", but the rules listed online are to pick 5 out of 50 and 2 out of 10. This makes the odds 1:(50.choose.5 * 10.choose.2), or 1:95344200.

Comment: @pjs oh I misspelled the variable, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would never match since the given numbers are unsorted and you are sorting the random result to match.

```
# first
given = [[8, 16, 12, 46, 47], [2, 4]] # the given 5 are unsorted
...
# get random numbers
tenOutOf50 = random.sample(range(1, 50), 5) 
twoOutOf10 = random.sample(range(1, 10), 2)

# and here is the problem
tenOutOf50.sort()
twoOutOf10.sort()
```

Just to point out, I am not saying that you cannot sort the random pick... I am just pointing why you could have it running for life.

EDIT: You should use a different approach for the `while` condition. As it is written now, you would never see the true condition as it would never enter it... So this code would not be executed:

```
if(given.__contains__(solution[0]) and given.__contains__(solution[1])):
    print(colored(0, 255, 0, solution))
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it my while condition with a simple infinite loop and break it as soon as a solution was found:

[image: solution]